# Cannot use named parameters with ST_AsMVT

Tags: postgresql, postgis

**Postgres 14**, **PostGIS 3.1**

I am unable to use named parameters in `ST_AsMVT`, e.g.,

```sql
SELECT
  ST_AsMVT(mvt_geom.*, feature_id_name => ('id'::text)) FROM mvt_geom;`
```

results in

```
ERROR:  function st_asmvt(record, feature_id_name => text) does not exist
```

On the other hand, I can use them in `ST_AsMVTGeom`, e.g., the following is successful.

```sql
SELECT
  ST_AsMVTGeom (geom, bbox, clip_geom => true)
```

Is there something particular about ST_AsMVT that prevents the usage of named parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ST_AsMVTGeom has default values for arguments 3 through 5, so they do not need to be specified.

The form of ST_AsMVT which accepts feature_id_name has 4 other *mandatory* arguments, but you only specify one other parameter.

Comment: ah interesting, so even though they have defaults, they “lose” those if using named syntax

Comment: The problem is that they *don't* have defaults.  So they need to be specified in one way or the other.

Comment: According to the docs (https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsMVT.html) they do have defaults, e.g.,
"extent is the tile extent in screen space as defined by the specification. Default is 4096."

Comment: Whereas in ST_AsMVTGeom docs, the phrasing is "extent is the tile extent in tile coordinate space as defined by the specification. If NULL it will default to 4096."

Comment: So it seems the "If NULL it will default to" vs "Default is" makes a difference. All defaults are defaults, but some defaults are more default than others.